# color input with transparency

Tags: html, css, colors, alpha

Is it possible to select transparent colors using built in

`<input type="color">`

I haven't found a slider that does that. Is there some option additional I need to check?

Answer (score 9):

AFAIK there's no option for transparent color picking using `<input type="color">`, but what you could do is have another input for the alpha, and set the opacity of the color input like this:

```js
function updateColorAlpha (alpha) {
    document.getElementById('color').style.opacity = alpha;
}
```

```html
<input type="color" id="color">
<input type="range" id="alpha" onchange="updateColorAlpha(this.value);" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="1">
```

Comment: This is a very clever way of showing the user what their opacity is going to look like!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible natively. The color picker only ever returns a hex code, which has no way to represent transparency. You would need to build something bespoke (or have a picker for color and one for transparency and do the calculation behind the scenes yourself).

For more information, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/color#Value

Answer (score 0):

You can use an an `<input type=range>` along with the `<input type=color>`to achieve your purpose. There is no HTML *"direct"* way to do it.

```
<input type="color" oninput = "setColor()" id = "color">
<br />
<input type="range" min="0" max="1" step = "0.1" onchange = "setColor()" id = "opacity" value = "1">
<div id = "result" style = "height:50px; width:50px;">
</div>

<script>
    function setColor() {
        var color = document.getElementById('color').value;
        var opacity = document.getElementById('opacity').value;
        document.getElementById('result').style.background = color;
        document.getElementById('result').style.opacity = opacity;
    }
    setColor();
</script>
```

You get the value of required opacity from the input type range by Javascript following which you set the color and opacity on the result element (the `div` in this case)

Note that if you require a more *"customizable"* solution you could try the jQuery plugin at [Picker.js](http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Lightweight-Color-Opacity-Picker-Plugin-with-jQuery-Picker-js.html)

Answer (score 0):

A method with less code by [prompt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) and [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*)

```
<input type="color" onchange="(e=>e.dataset.alpha = prompt('alpha'))(this)">
```

#### Example

```html
<input type="color" value="#ffff00"
       data-alpha="#ffffff"
       onchange="(e=>e.dataset.alpha = prompt('alpha', e.dataset.alpha ?? 'transparent'))(this)"
>
<!--  just for test -->
<br>
<button>Get Result</button>
<script>
   document.querySelector("button").onclick = () => {
    const e = document.querySelector("input")
    console.log(e.value, e.dataset.alpha)   
   }
</script>
```

Additionally, if you want to directly access alpha more succinctly, that is,

<del>e.dataset.alpha</del> => `e.alpha`,

you can use [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) to assist.

```html
<input type="color" value="#ffff00"  
  data-alpha="transparent" 
  onchange="(e=>e.dataset.alpha = prompt('alpha'))(this)">
<button onclick="getResult()">get result</button>

<script>
function ColorEx(inputColorElem) {
  return new Proxy(inputColorElem, {
    get(target, key) {
      return key!=="alpha" ? target[key] : target.dataset.alpha
    }
  })
}

function getResult() {
  const e = new ColorEx(document.querySelector("input[data-alpha]"))
  console.log(e.value, e.alpha)
}
</script>
```