# how to set transparent as default value in an input color

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have four color input fields in my html code. The default color is black. I want the default to be transparent so the user knows at a glance that a color hasn't been chosen yet.

This does not work.
I've searched the web, but couldn't find a solution to this.

Is there a way to set the default value of the color input to transparent?

I am looking for a solution in css/javascript. Ultimately, jquery.

```js
document.getElementById("inputPersonalizacionCabecera").defaultValue = "rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.8)";
document.getElementById("inputPersonalizacionFooter").defaultValue = "rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.8)";
document.getElementById("inputPersonalizacionBotones").defaultValue = "rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.8)";
document.getElementById("inputPersonalizacionEnlaces").defaultValue = "rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.8)";
```

```css
input#inputPersonalizacionCabecera,
input#inputPersonalizacionFooter,
input#inputPersonalizacionBotones,
input#inputPersonalizacionEnlaces {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="form-row">

  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="inputPersonalizacionCabecera">Color de la <span style="color: #93c47d;font-weight: 600;">cabecera</span></label>
    <input type="color" value="#ffffff" class="form-control" id="inputPersonalizacionCabecera" name="inputPersonalizacionCabecera"></input>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="inputPersonalizacionFooter">Color del <span style="color: #6fa8dc;font-weight: 600;">pie de página</span></label>
    <input type="color" value="#ffffff" class="form-control" id="inputPersonalizacionFooter" name="inputPersonalizacionFooter">
  </div>

</div>

<div class="form-row">

  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="inputPersonalizacionBotones">Color de los <span style="color: #f6b26b;font-weight: 600;">botones</span></label>
    <input type="color" value="#ffffff" class="form-control" id="inputPersonalizacionBotones" name="inputPersonalizacionBotones">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="inputPersonalizacionEnlaces">Color de los <span style="color: #b4a7d6;font-weight: 600;">enlaces</span></label>
    <input type="color" value="#ffffff" class="form-control" id="inputPersonalizacionEnlaces" name="inputPersonalizacionEnlaces">
  </div>            

</div>
```

Comment: "transparent" isn't a color. Opacity is a separate CSS attribute.

Comment: @Barmar I know that transparent is not a color. My intention is to put a white color and give it the necessary opacity to achieve the desired transparency. The problem I'm having is that I don't see a way to give that "opacity" as a default value to the color input.

Comment: Have you noticed color pickers in other application, like Photoshop, GIMP etc. Opacity/transparency is always a separate property. It doesn't make sense to have either transparent or a color. Often you would like a half transparent blue or whatever. Users will prefer a color picker and den a opacity scale to chose from.

Comment: input of type color doesn't consider transparency. You need to have a separate selector for the opacity. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46503249/color-input-with-transparency